# Problems sending/receiving UDP in python

Tags: python, networking, udp

I'm trying to send data over UDP point to point (looping back to a second NIC) but am losing data.  Here is the code (from: [sending/receiving file UDP in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993514/sending-receiving-file-udp-in-python/13994479#13994479)):

## ----- sender.py ------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
import sys

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
host =sys.argv[1]
port = 9999
buf =1024
addr = (host,port)

file_name=sys.argv[2]

s.sendto(file_name,addr)

f=open(file_name,"rb")
data = f.read(buf)
while (data):
    if(s.sendto(data,addr)):
        #print "sending ..."
        data = f.read(buf)
s.close()
f.close()
```

## ----- receiver.py -----

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
import sys
import select

host="192.0.0.2" #second nic
port = 9999
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

addr = (host,port)
buf=1024

data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
print "Received File:",data.strip()
f = open(data.strip(),'wb')

data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
try:
    while(data):
        f.write(data)
        s.settimeout(2)
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
except timeout:
    f.close()
    s.close()
    print "File Downloaded"
```

I create my file with dd:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test_file bs=1024 count=100
```

I found that when count is over approx 100 it starts to fail.  I tried different bs all the way down to 32 and it still fails.  When I change bs I change buf in the code to match.  I repeat creating a new file and running the command in a loop.  With different combinations, sometimes it fails every transfer, sometimes it fails in a pattern (ie every 5)

I found that if I add a delay in the while loop in sender to delay by 0.0005 seconds, then it works fine and I can send any amount of data.  If I bring the delay down to 0.0001, then it fails again.  I'm getting approx 1.5MB/sec

I'd appreciate any recommendations to improve my performance.  I am thinking that perhaps there is a receive buffer that is overflowing and I'm just not reading it fast enough.

Comment: UDP has no error checking or automatic retries. If you try to send too quickly, you can run out of socket buffers and packets will be discarded.

Comment: It could be happening at the sending or receiving end.

Comment: The `bs` used by `dd` is just the number of bytes to write in each write to the output file and has no effect on the final file and `count` is just the number of those write to perform. Are you constrained to using `UDP` and not `TCP`? Communiction using `UDP` is not guaranteed to be without errors.

Comment: I think you are right. Your operating system drops frames because your `udp` buffer is full. Use `tcp`, if you want to avoid this from happening. If you want to improve performance I would try to buffer the read data into memory and write it to disk in bigger junks (100MiB or so). Increasing the `udp` buffer size at the same time should also help.

Comment: I must use UDP because this will eventually be a one way link.  Is the UDP buffer the OS UDP buffer? or are there other buffers?  I see, I could buffer the data in memory and write it out (perhaps in another thread).  Hopefully python itself is not too slow.

Comment: I tried writing everything to a queue first but it was actually slower than writing to a file. (I am testing in /tmp which is a ramdrive).  Is there a different way I should be buffering that would be faster? Perhaps I should use C code instead.  Anyways, increasing the OS receive buffer to 25MB got it to work sending 100mb files.  I had to increase the buffer to nearly 1GB for 1GB files

Comment: yes, I meant the operating system's udp buffer size. `net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.rmem_default` are the parameters you want to tweak under linux. In addition I would increate the `buf` variable on the receiver side.