# Python socket data not being sent

Tags: python, networking, udp

I'm trying to send data over UDP point to point (looping back to a second NIC) but it is not working. (This will be a one way connection which is why I am using UDP). I'm using Python 2.6.6.  Here is the code (from: [sending/receiving file UDP in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993514/sending-receiving-file-udp-in-python/13994479#13994479)):

## ----- sender.py ------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
import sys

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("192.168.0.1",9999))
host = "192.168.100.1"
port = 9999
buf =1024
addr = (host,port)

file_name=sys.argv[1]

s.sendto(file_name,addr)

f=open(file_name,"rb")
data = f.read(buf)
while (data):
    if(s.sendto(data,addr)):
        #print "sending ..."
        data = f.read(buf)
s.close()
f.close()
```

## ----- receiver.py -----

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
import sys
import select

host="192.168.100.1" #second nic
port = 9999
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

addr = (host,port)
buf=1024

data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
print "Received File:",data.strip()
f = open(data.strip(),'wb')

data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
try:
    while(data):
        f.write(data)
        s.settimeout(2)
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
except timeout:
    f.close()
    s.close()
    print "File Downloaded"
```

I can see both interfaces using `ifconfig`.  `eth0` is `192.168.0.1` and `eth1` is `192.168.100.1`.  If I try `ping -I eth0 192.168.100.1`, I see packets sent on `eth0` and received on `eth1`.  This seems to confirm the interface works.  However, if I run the above python script, I see no packets being sent or received on either interface.

Comment: you really need to do something to deal with errors!  some sort of sequence number so the receiver knows if it's missing/duplicating/getting out-of-order packets, and/or maybe use something like [FEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) so it's got a chance of handling data that goes wrong

Comment: I agree, but I'm losing 100% now.  It seems that nothing is being sent.  I'd like to figure this out first.

Comment: since your last question you seem to be `bind`ing in the sender...  are you sure this is doing the right thing?  have you got routes set up properly so it knows what to do in this case?

Comment: also, you can still use `connect()` with UDP, which should give you better errors back from the OS, e.g. about hosts not being reachable, as well as being slightly faster due to not needing to check the hostname on every `send`

Comment: also, when you say "I see no packets being sent or received on either interface" how are you determining this?  do you have `tcpdump`, wireshark, or something similar running?

Comment: In my last question, I thought it was working but it was going through loopback so I created this.  I think I need to bind in both.  I'll try connect.  I'm not using host names. I didnt think tcpdump would work since I am using UDP.  I am just looking at bytes sent/received in ifconfig.

Comment: tcpdump is lower level than either UDP or TCP, it'll happily show either, or ICMP packets, ARP resolution and AFAIK basically anything the network card sees (unless use a BPF rule that filters it out)

Comment: your `bind` in sender also looks wrong, is this a typo when creating the question?  you need to pass a tuple, not two parameters.  are you sure you're running the version of the code you think you are?

Comment: sorry that was a typo.  I looked at tcpdump and see no activity when the python script is sending.  When you mention setting up routes, what do you mean?  The only setting I did (in addition to the IPs) was adding ARP entries for each interface.

Comment: I tried adding `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "eth0"+'\0')` and now I see `Request who-has 192.168.100.1 tell 192.168.0.1` in tcpdump.  I do have a ARP table entry for each interface.

Comment: From reading this: https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface/128680  I've tried the instructions and now I can see it sending and receiving data via tcpdump on both interfaces.  However, the python receiver still is not receiving anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196537/discussion-between-sam-mason-and-eng3).

Comment: ok I got it to work.  I had a typo in the commands that I copied from the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong ip in your code.

host="192.0.100.1" #second nic

Your description says the ips are 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.0.1

Comment: sorry that was a typo